# Laravel API login with JWT authentication token storage

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, jwt

I'm creating a mobile/app and i'm using the Laravel framework. For the API login i'm using JWT auth. This works fine but I have a few questions about the storage of the token. At the moment i'm sending the token in the header. But when I switch pages the headers are gone. Should I keep the token in the header or is it better to save it in a Laravel database sessions. Is there a way to keep the token in the header when i switch to another function? Hope someone can help me out, been thinking for days about this.

Comment: Not sure, if I understand you completely. But you don't need to store the token on the server, it should be resent to the server with each request of the client (the server is stateless normally). The client must ensure to store the token which is often done in the local storage.

Comment: it is better to save token in DB

Comment: I've read some unsafe things about saving the token in the local storage. It could be hijacked and the hacker can login with admin rights when he has the token.

Comment: You should not worry about CSRF from saving token in local storage as long as you build an app with security in mind. Read on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) for more information. Basically, any time you are taking user input (whether it's text, an image URL, or anything like that) that will be rendered back into the DOM at a later time, *sanitize the input*. Using a UI framework like Angular will take care of this for you behind the scenes so you never have to worry about it.